# "No .app bundles found in the package"

Tags: ios, submit

"No .app bundles found in the package"

I am getting this error when submitting the application from the application uploader.

I am able to build the application and run it from the simulator, and all of the certs seem to be in place.

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem developing my apps in XCode 7.3.1 with OS X El Capitan and then update to macOS Sierra and Xcode 8.

I can solve this problem following the next steps:

1. Archive your app with Xcode 7.3.1 (download in developer.apple.com)
2. When you archived your app, find your archive in the Organizer, and then:

"Show in finder";

"Show package contents";

In the "xx.xcarchive" file, find the "Products"-"Applications"-"xx.app"(xx is your app's name), "Show package contents" again;

Finally, you can see there has a file named"Info.plist", 
open it;

Edit the value with a key named "BuildMachineOSBuild", I just change it to "16A323"(it's "macOS Sierra" 's version);

Edit the value with a key named "DTXcodeBuild" with the Xcode 8 version number "8A218a"

After that, you can upload this archive use Xcode 8 or Application Loader in macOS Sierra, whatever you want!

[Info.plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U14Te.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are possibly zipping your bundle before build completion - if you are driving fast it can happen :)